# PyCharm error and no suggestions come up

Tags: python, pycharm

Please help me here , I got IDE error and below is the error log
but now I am also no getting suggestions when I type like when I type import s than nothing is suggested. please help correct this issue

```
com.jetbrains.edu.learning.PyStudyImportResolver.resolveImportReference(Lcom/intellij/psi/util/QualifiedName;Lcom/jetbrains/python/psi/resolve/PyQualifiedNameResolveContext;Z)Lcom/intellij/psi/PsiElement;
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.jetbrains.edu.learning.PyStudyImportResolver.resolveImportReference(Lcom/intellij/psi/util/QualifiedName;Lcom/jetbrains/python/psi/resolve/PyQualifiedNameResolveContext;Z)Lcom/intellij/psi/PsiElement;
    at com.jetbrains.python.psi.resolve.PyResolveImportUtil$foreignResults$1.invoke(PyResolveImportUtil.kt:168)
    at com.jetbrains.python.psi.resolve.PyResolveImportUtil$foreignResults$1.invoke(PyResolveImportUtil.kt)
    at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.next(Sequences.kt:147)
    at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.calcNext(Sequences.kt:108)
    at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:131)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toCollection(_Sequences.kt:630)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toMutableList(_Sequences.kt:660)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toList(_Sequences.kt:651)
    at com.jetbrains.python.psi.resolve.PyResolveImportUtil.foreignResults(PyResolveImportUtil.kt:170)
    at com.jetbrains.python.psi.resolve.PyResolveImportUtil.resolveQualifiedName(PyResolveImportUtil.kt:81)
    at com.jetbrains.python.psi.impl.PyBuiltinCache.getSkeletonFile(PyBuiltinCache.java:147)
    at com.jetbrains.python.psi.impl.PyBuiltinCache.getBuiltinsForSdk(PyBuiltinCache.java:131)
    at com.jetbrains.python.psi.resolve.PythonSdkPathCache.getBuiltins(PythonSdkPathCache.java:117)
    at com.jetbrains.python.psi.impl.PyBuiltinCache.getInstance(PyBuiltinCache.java:85)
    at com.jetbrains.python.inspections.PyPropertyDefinitionInspection$Visitor.<init>(PyPropertyDefinitionInspection.java:88)
    at com.jetbrains.python.inspections.PyPropertyDefinitionInspection.buildVisitor(PyPropertyDefinitionInspection.java:71)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionEngine.createVisitorAndAcceptElements(InspectionEngine.java:60)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.runToolOnElements(LocalInspectionsPass.java:282)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.lambda$visitPriorityElementsAndInit$3(LocalInspectionsPass.java:250)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.execAndForkSubTasks(ApplierCompleter.java:133)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1147)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.lambda$wrapInReadActionAndIndicator$1(ApplierCompleter.java:105)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.wrapInReadActionAndIndicator(ApplierCompleter.java:116)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.lambda$compute$0(ApplierCompleter.java:96)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ReadMostlyRWLock.executeByImpatientReader(ReadMostlyRWLock.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.executeByImpatientReader(ApplicationImpl.java:242)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.compute(ApplierCompleter.java:96)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.pollAndExecCC(ForkJoinPool.java:1190)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.helpComplete(ForkJoinPool.java:1879)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.awaitJoin(ForkJoinPool.java:2045)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doJoin(ForkJoinTask.java:390)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:719)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.invoke(ForkJoinPool.java:2616)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl.invokeConcurrentlyUnderProgress(JobLauncherImpl.java:63)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncher.invokeConcurrentlyUnderProgress(JobLauncher.java:57)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.visitPriorityElementsAndInit(LocalInspectionsPass.java:253)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.inspect(LocalInspectionsPass.java:223)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.collectInformationWithProgress(LocalInspectionsPass.java:132)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.ProgressableTextEditorHighlightingPass.doCollectInformation(ProgressableTextEditorHighlightingPass.java:83)
    at com.intellij.codeHighlighting.TextEditorHighlightingPass.collectInformation(TextEditorHighlightingPass.java:70)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$null$1(PassExecutorService.java:438)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1153)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$doRun$2(PassExecutorService.java:431)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.doRun(PassExecutorService.java:430)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$run$0(PassExecutorService.java:406)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ReadMostlyRWLock.executeByImpatientReader(ReadMostlyRWLock.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.executeByImpatientReader(ApplicationImpl.java:242)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.run(PassExecutorService.java:404)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl$VoidForkJoinTask$1.exec(JobLauncherImpl.java:165)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)


java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.jetbrains.edu.learning.PyStudyImportResolver.resolveImportReference(Lcom/intellij/psi/util/QualifiedName;Lcom/jetbrains/python/psi/resolve/PyQualifiedNameResolveContext;Z)Lcom/intellij/psi/PsiElement;
    at com.jetbrains.python.psi.resolve.PyResolveImportUtil$foreignResults$1.invoke(PyResolveImportUtil.kt:168)
    at com.jetbrains.python.psi.resolve.PyResolveImportUtil$foreignResults$1.invoke(PyResolveImportUtil.kt)
    at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.next(Sequences.kt:147)
    at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.calcNext(Sequences.kt:108)
    at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:131)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toCollection(_Sequences.kt:630)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toMutableList(_Sequences.kt:660)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toList(_Sequences.kt:651)
    at com.jetbrains.python.psi.resolve.PyResolveImportUtil.foreignResults(PyResolveImportUtil.kt:170)
    at com.jetbrains.python.psi.resolve.PyResolveImportUtil.resolveQualifiedName(PyResolveImportUtil.kt:81)
    at com.jetbrains.python.psi.impl.PyBuiltinCache.getSkeletonFile(PyBuiltinCache.java:147)
    at com.jetbrains.python.psi.impl.PyBuiltinCache.getBuiltinsForSdk(PyBuiltinCache.java:131)
    at com.jetbrains.python.psi.resolve.PythonSdkPathCache.getBuiltins(PythonSdkPathCache.java:117)
    at com.jetbrains.python.psi.impl.PyBuiltinCache.getInstance(PyBuiltinCache.java:85)
    at com.jetbrains.python.inspections.PyPropertyDefinitionInspection$Visitor.<init>(PyPropertyDefinitionInspection.java:88)
    at com.jetbrains.python.inspections.PyPropertyDefinitionInspection.buildVisitor(PyPropertyDefinitionInspection.java:71)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionEngine.createVisitorAndAcceptElements(InspectionEngine.java:60)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.runToolOnElements(LocalInspectionsPass.java:282)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.lambda$visitPriorityElementsAndInit$3(LocalInspectionsPass.java:250)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.execAndForkSubTasks(ApplierCompleter.java:133)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1147)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.lambda$wrapInReadActionAndIndicator$1(ApplierCompleter.java:105)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.wrapInReadActionAndIndicator(ApplierCompleter.java:116)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.lambda$compute$0(ApplierCompleter.java:96)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ReadMostlyRWLock.executeByImpatientReader(ReadMostlyRWLock.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.executeByImpatientReader(ApplicationImpl.java:242)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.compute(ApplierCompleter.java:96)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.pollAndExecCC(ForkJoinPool.java:1190)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.helpComplete(ForkJoinPool.java:1879)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.awaitJoin(ForkJoinPool.java:2045)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doJoin(ForkJoinTask.java:390)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:719)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.invoke(ForkJoinPool.java:2616)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl.invokeConcurrentlyUnderProgress(JobLauncherImpl.java:63)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncher.invokeConcurrentlyUnderProgress(JobLauncher.java:57)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.visitPriorityElementsAndInit(LocalInspectionsPass.java:253)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.inspect(LocalInspectionsPass.java:223)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.collectInformationWithProgress(LocalInspectionsPass.java:132)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.ProgressableTextEditorHighlightingPass.doCollectInformation(ProgressableTextEditorHighlightingPass.java:83)
    at com.intellij.codeHighlighting.TextEditorHighlightingPass.collectInformation(TextEditorHighlightingPass.java:70)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$null$1(PassExecutorService.java:438)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1153)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$doRun$2(PassExecutorService.java:431)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.doRun(PassExecutorService.java:430)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$run$0(PassExecutorService.java:406)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ReadMostlyRWLock.executeByImpatientReader(ReadMostlyRWLock.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.executeByImpatientReader(ApplicationImpl.java:242)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.run(PassExecutorService.java:404)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl$VoidForkJoinTask$1.exec(JobLauncherImpl.java:165)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)


java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.jetbrains.edu.learning.PyStudyImportResolver.resolveImportReference(Lcom/intellij/psi/util/QualifiedName;Lcom/jetbrains/python/psi/resolve/PyQualifiedNameResolveContext;Z)Lcom/intellij/psi/PsiElement;
    at com.jetbrains.python.psi.resolve.PyResolveImportUtil$foreignResults$1.invoke(PyResolveImportUtil.kt:168)
    at com.jetbrains.python.psi.resolve.PyResolveImportUtil$foreignResults$1.invoke(PyResolveImportUtil.kt)
    at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.next(Sequences.kt:147)
    at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.calcNext(Sequences.kt:108)
    at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:131)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toCollection(_Sequences.kt:630)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toMutableList(_Sequences.kt:660)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toList(_Sequences.kt:651)
    at com.jetbrains.python.psi.resolve.PyResolveImportUtil.foreignResults(PyResolveImportUtil.kt:170)
    at com.jetbrains.python.psi.resolve.PyResolveImportUtil.resolveQualifiedName(PyResolveImportUtil.kt:81)
    at com.jetbrains.python.psi.impl.PyBuiltinCache.getSkeletonFile(PyBuiltinCache.java:147)
    at com.jetbrains.python.psi.impl.PyBuiltinCache.getBuiltinsForSdk(PyBuiltinCache.java:131)
    at com.jetbrains.python.psi.resolve.PythonSdkPathCache.getBuiltins(PythonSdkPathCache.java:117)
    at com.jetbrains.python.psi.impl.PyBuiltinCache.getInstance(PyBuiltinCache.java:85)
    at com.jetbrains.python.psi.impl.references.PyReferenceImpl.getVariants(PyReferenceImpl.java:640)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionData.completeReference(CompletionData.java:273)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionVariant.addReferenceCompletions(CompletionVariant.java:137)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionData.completeReference(CompletionData.java:81)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.LegacyCompletionContributor.lambda$completeReference$0(LegacyCompletionContributor.java:71)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.LegacyCompletionContributor.processReference(LegacyCompletionContributor.java:125)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.LegacyCompletionContributor.processReferences(LegacyCompletionContributor.java:108)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.LegacyCompletionContributor.completeReference(LegacyCompletionContributor.java:69)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.LegacyCompletionContributor.fillCompletionVariants(LegacyCompletionContributor.java:52)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionService.getVariantsFromContributors(CompletionService.java:81)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionResultSet.runRemainingContributors(CompletionResultSet.java:138)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionResultSet.runRemainingContributors(CompletionResultSet.java:131)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.template.impl.LiveTemplateCompletionContributor$2.addCompletions(LiveTemplateCompletionContributor.java:88)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionProvider.addCompletionVariants(CompletionProvider.java:36)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionContributor.fillCompletionVariants(CompletionContributor.java:151)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionService.getVariantsFromContributors(CompletionService.java:81)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionService.performCompletion(CompletionService.java:110)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionProgressIndicator.calculateItems(CompletionProgressIndicator.java:831)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionProgressIndicator.access$600(CompletionProgressIndicator.java:93)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionProgressIndicator$1CalculateItems.run(CompletionProgressIndicator.java:813)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.AsyncCompletion.lambda$null$0(CompletionThreading.java:108)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:931)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.AsyncCompletion.lambda$null$1(CompletionThreading.java:105)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.AsyncCompletion.lambda$startThread$2(CompletionThreading.java:103)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you show your code instead of the the log file?

Comment: I would recommend restarting PyCharm if you haven't tried that yet.

Comment: happens to me as well I'm using pycharm 2017.2